# Proper Structure

Tags: vb.net, oop, webforms

I am building a webforms app using a 3 tier model and ado.net. (UI code behind) (middle tier 'classes') (DAL). Although EF would be a good fit, I would like to avoid it for this project as I am not familiar with it.

My database has a few tables and they have foreign key relationships between the tables. The app will have simple display, add, update, delete functions for each table.

I have created a class for each table that outlines the properties which correspond to each database column. So my question is how to handle the relationships between the tables, here is a simple example-

Table 'cars'
CarID
OwnerID
ColorID
Make
Model

Table 'Owners'
OwnerID
Fname
Lname

Table 'Colors'
ColorID
ColorName

On the Cars 'management' page -
The Owners and color tables should be represented as dropdownlists.

Do I load/bind the 'Owners' and 'Colors' lists with separate ado queries and simply save the 'IDs' of each field using the 'Cars' class or is there a way to tie these together, it seams there would be a more efficient way rather then making multiple database dips to pull the lists.

Any thoughts or comments welcome and appreciated.

Comment: If you set the foreign keys in the database and build the model from that you will have navigation properties in each table.

Comment: You might be able to add them manually, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, to clarify I am not using entity framework in this app, I did however play around with it and built the model as you said and it had the relationships built in, although i didn't understand the implementation.

Comment: There is an `EntityDataSource` for your `WebForm` and there is much documentation out there for it. Then you bind controls to this.